# Could it be correct to have two Google Analytics UA codes in my site?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, universal-analytics

[image]

OK, I started out on a new job and working on SEO. I saw that it has two UA codes. Since I am a newbie on this, I wanted to know if the use of these codes are correct? Just wanted to know if there is a purpose for this? That's it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem having two GA codes on your website and the purpose of it could be multiple.

From having data from an old GA account that they want to keep and not lose to forgetting that the old code was there to specifically wanting to use two accounts to track it.

The better option would be to ask colleges if there is a specific reason there are two codes there as the usual implementation is just to have one.